# Spring Security removeAuthorizationRequest of HttpSessionOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository always return null

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm using spring security with oauth client also spring session data redis to store session data in redis storage. so when i attempting to authenticate with oauth the corresponding request data stored in redis. The data looks like this

```json
{
   "authorizationUri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth",
   "responseType":"code",
   "clientId":"***.apps.googleusercontent.com",
   "redirectUri":"http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/google",
   "scopes":[
      "openid",
      "profile",
      "email"
   ],
   "state":"y829XucK_617Xrl5O4QEk8EfpvuWkaE7G8MUN0HV5ok=",
   "additionalParameters":{
      "nonce":"Z00EwZrkziuO31XVt4RK1tkApUEOjTG4SpzHp94ASxE"
   },
   "authorizationRequestUri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=***.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=openid%20profile%20email&state=y829XucK_617Xrl5O4QEk8EfpvuWkaE7G8MUN0HV5ok%3D&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/google&nonce=Z00EwZrkziuO31XVt4RK1tkApUEOjTG4SpzHp94ASxE",
   "attributes":{
      "registration_id":"google",
      "nonce":"86o0mT1_uDmbcwDHciWPsxft2Vlo0WyHXZRda2N9a0a00yb7puxLhPqIUNOov--PUt-HRlqb5rpVYXTahlGsCzPTn6wm7ZaD2gNI13HMPqN-IX4oRfAmWbKpi4-7TbPV"
   },
   "grantType":{
      "value":"authorization_code"
   }
}
```

along with the authenticating process there is `HttpSessionOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository` class and the method `removeAuthorizationRequest` which cause my problem that always returning null value

```java
@Override
public OAuth2AuthorizationRequest removeAuthorizationRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
    Assert.notNull(request, "request cannot be null");
    String stateParameter = this.getStateParameter(request);
    if (stateParameter == null) {
        return null;
    }
    Map<String, OAuth2AuthorizationRequest> authorizationRequests = this.getAuthorizationRequests(request);
    OAuth2AuthorizationRequest originalRequest = authorizationRequests.remove(stateParameter);
    if (authorizationRequests.size() == 0) {
        request.getSession().removeAttribute(this.sessionAttributeName);
    }
    else if (authorizationRequests.size() == 1) {
        request.getSession().setAttribute(this.sessionAttributeName,
                authorizationRequests.values().iterator().next());
    }
    else {
        request.getSession().setAttribute(this.sessionAttributeName, authorizationRequests);
    }
    return originalRequest;
}
```

As you can see the 2nd statement retrieve the state value so it would be `String stateParameter = "y829XucK_617Xrl5O4QEk8EfpvuWkaE7G8MUN0HV5ok="` and the variable `authorizationRequests` in 6 lines has the same value as the json data above but as map type. right next statement it try to execute remove some value but as i said the parameter `stateParameter` is not `key` it is `value` so the result of this statement is always `null`.

And the caller part of this method looks like this

```java
@Override
public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws AuthenticationException {
    MultiValueMap<String, String> params = OAuth2AuthorizationResponseUtils.toMultiMap(request.getParameterMap());
    if (!OAuth2AuthorizationResponseUtils.isAuthorizationResponse(params)) {
        OAuth2Error oauth2Error = new OAuth2Error(OAuth2ErrorCodes.INVALID_REQUEST);
        throw new OAuth2AuthenticationException(oauth2Error, oauth2Error.toString());
    }
    OAuth2AuthorizationRequest authorizationRequest = this.authorizationRequestRepository
            .removeAuthorizationRequest(request, response);
    if (authorizationRequest == null) {
        OAuth2Error oauth2Error = new OAuth2Error(AUTHORIZATION_REQUEST_NOT_FOUND_ERROR_CODE);
        throw new OAuth2AuthenticationException(oauth2Error, oauth2Error.toString());
    }
    // The rest of code...
}
```

As you can see if the `authorizationRequest` is null then it always throws exception...
I don't think the code has problem because i couldn't find any similar issues in the whole web.

If you guys know about anything similar with my issues please let me know how i can resolve this issue...

And here is my setup

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.5'
}

sourceCompatibility = '11'

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis'
    implementation('org.springframework.session:spring-session-data-redis') {
        exclude group: 'org.springframework.data', module: 'spring-data-redis'
    }
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
}
```

This is stack trace

```
2023-02-09 16:35:07.947  WARN 59793 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] l.g.c.CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler : [authorization_request_not_found] 
org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.OAuth2AuthenticationException: [authorization_request_not_found] 
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter.java:173)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:227)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:217)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.doFilterInternal(OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:112)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:82)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:221)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:186)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:142)
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:82)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1789)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Here is reproducible repository
[sample repository](https://github.com/Y-k-Y/spring-security-test)

**EDIT**

- Added spring boot version and java version
- Added stack trace
- This is my initial setup no upgrade
- Added sample reproducible repository

Comment: Please share what version of spring you are using. Also, did you recently upgrade versions? Lastly, please share relevant trace logs if able so we can see the flow.

Comment: @SteveRiesenberg Thank you for your quick comment! As you said i added some additional info.